Interfacing MCP3550 ADC to ArduinoMega at Vref, VDD, Vin+ = 4.8 vin-=0, not getting reading of 4.8 on serial monitor, code is below, what is reason?
I'm getting reading on serial monitor as 1.2V Max and adc reading of 1042017, for different vref too adc reading is stuck at 1042017 so i think there is some bits missing during transfer may be? and one other thing i tried is if i divide 2^20 instead of 2^22 while calculating to print the value it is showing correct results so is it correct till 20 bits only?
#include <SPI.h>

const int chipSelectPin = 10;  // CS pin for MCP3550-60EN
const float VREF = 4.8;        // Reference Voltage

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  SPI.begin();
  pinMode(chipSelectPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(chipSelectPin, HIGH);
  
  // Set SPI speed to 500 kHz
  SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(500000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));
}

void loop() {
  long adcValue = readADC();  // Read the ADC value
  float voltage = (adcValue * VREF) / 4194304.0;  // Convert ADC value to voltage

  Serial.print("ADC Value: ");
  Serial.print(adcValue);
  Serial.print(" | Voltage: ");
  Serial.println(voltage, 4);  // Print voltage with 4 decimal places
  
  delay(200);  // Wait for 200 milliseconds before the next reading
}

// Function to read 22-bit data from MCP3550-60EN
long readADC() {
  unsigned long adcValue = 0;
  digitalWrite(chipSelectPin, LOW);
  
  // Wait until the ADC is ready (MISO goes low)
  while (digitalRead(MISO) == HIGH);
  
  // Read 22-bit data from MCP3550
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    adcValue <<= 8;  
    adcValue |= SPI.transfer(0x00);  
  }
  
  digitalWrite(chipSelectPin, HIGH);

  // Sign extend if the 22nd bit (sign bit) is 1
  if (adcValue & 0x200000) {
    adcValue |= 0xFFC00000;  
  }

  return (long)adcValue;  
}


https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/20001950F.pdf  Fig 2-16 of data show a dispersion of +/- 10 counts with results ... so +/- 5 bits noise.

@Antonio51 can u elaborate please?
